# How to check if attribute is present in value using Mule expression language

Tags: regex, xpath, mule, mule-studio, mule-el

I want to check logged in user’s authorization based on ‘groupmembership’ header attribute.

The output of

```
<logger level="INFO" message="groups are =#[message.inboundProperties['GROUPMEMBERSHIP']]" doc:name="Logger"/> is
[groups are =cn=ZZZ-XXXX-Write-Users,ou= ZZZ-XXXX,ou=1234,ou=Groups,dc=someone,dc=net]
```

Now a user can have multiple group memberships but all I am interested in checking if user is member of ‘ZZZ-XXXX-Write-Users’?

Is there a way in MEL to check that, something like 
`<when expression="#[message.inboundProperties.GROUPMEMBERSHIP.cn != ' ZZZ-XXXX-Write-Users ']">`

Is this the right approach or am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scenario you describe looks more like a flow control stuff. 
In that case I would say that you use just that MEL expression inside a choice router:

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
  <when expression="#[!message.inboundProperties.GROUPMEMBERSHIP.cn.equals('ZZZ-XXXX-Write-Users')]">
    <!-- DO SOMETHING -->
  </when
  <otherwise>
   <!-- DO SOMETHING ELSE -->
  </otherwise>
</choice>
```

Just a small change the use of equals to compare strings ;).

The other option, as we are talking flow control here, is a filter.
A expression filter will just ignore the message if the expression doesn't evaluate to true. The catch with this is, it either pass or not you can not have an alternative route not even a log message saying that a message was filtered.

```
    <expression-filter expression="#[!message.inboundProperties.GROUPMEMBERSHIP.cn.equals('ZZZ-XXXX-Write-Users')]" doc:name="Expression"/>
```

HTH

Comment: Well this failed to work as I was looking for more like contains operation of java String. I tried MEL contains  operator but that never really worked after multiple trials. Even I got the payload to a variable and tried with MEL contains but was not of much help. I ended up writing a customer transformer. Here I got payload to String and then used Java Strings Contains method and sent back the result.

Comment: Well if it's a MEL expression what you want you could contribute your java transformer like a mel function something like :

    `<configuration doc:name="Configuration">
      <expression-language autoResolveVariables="false">
            <global-functions >
                      def your_func(e){app.registry['your_bean'].your_method(e)}
            <global-functions >
      </expression-language>
</configuration>`